# Notice: SHUTDOWN tag now available

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed we've gotten several questions about the shutdown of the United States government.  I think these deserve their own tag, so I've added it.  It's probably good to have a separate stream for this event.

Comment: Unless "shutdown" is an official term in the law, I would strongly recommend renaming the tag to a more accurate "slimdown". Federal government isn't "shut down", merely parts of it are.

Comment: I don't care what the reality is - the media are going with shutdown.  Tags aren't about what things should be, they are about what people actually say - no matter how inaccurate

Comment: i can provide example of media using "slimdown", so I don't think THAT reason holds much water.

Comment: If you want a synonym, go for it!